# What does it means this +1 in Permutation List with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, permutation

This permutation comes from Udacity and is made with Python.
But i have problems to understand what does it means +1 in this line `for j in range(0, len(p) + 1):`. Someone could help me to understand it? I'm little bit confused.

Thanks to all!

```
import copy
def permute(l):

    perm = []
    if len(l) == 0:
        perm.append([])
    else:
        first_element = l[0]
        after_first = slice(1, None)
        sub_permutes = permute(l[after_first])
        for p in sub_permutes:
            for j in range(0, len(p) + 1):
                r = copy.deepcopy(p)
                r.insert(j, first_element)
                perm.append(r)
    return perm
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind this loop is to create a lists each with `first_element` in different place.

To insert an element after the last index (mimic `append` behavior), you would write `l.insert(len(l), element)`). So when they are trying to insert the first element in each place of the list they want the `range` to be from `0` to `len(p)` and be inclusive, so they add `+1` to the range.

```py
In [1]: l = [1,2,3]
In [2]: for i in range(0, len(l)+1):
   ...:     new_l = list(l)
   ...:     new_l.insert(i, 4)
   ...:     print(new_l)
   ...:
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4] # without the +1 this line would not be created
```